# Can not connect with click-house running inside docker with nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, clickhouse

I have downloaded this click-house docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/clickhouse/clickhouse-server/

I started click-house server with the following command

```js
docker run  --network=host --name some-clickhouse-server --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 clickhouse/clickhouse-server
```

I connected with clickhouse with the following command

```js
docker exec -it some-clickhouse-server clickhouse-client
```

Output of the above command

```
ClickHouse client version 24.1.5.6 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Connected to ClickHouse server version 24.1.5.

Warnings:
 * Delay accounting is not enabled, OSIOWaitMicroseconds will not be gathered. Check /proc/sys/kernel/task_delayacct
```

As you can see in the above command click house is using port `9000`.

### Problem

AS per the [docs](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/http), click-house has HTTP Interface which listens on port `8123` by default. I tried to access `8123` port using my browser, but i got the following error.

> Same is true for port `9000` as well.

[image]

I am using `host` network in docker, so I should be able to connect this interface from my browser.

Same is happening for nodejs as well

```js
const { ClickHouse } = require("clickhouse");
const clickhouse = new ClickHouse({
  url: "http://localhost",
  port: 9000,
});
```

Getting the following error on terminal

```
Error inserting row: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:9000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1532:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 9000
}
```

Here is [docs](https://github.com/TimonKK/clickhouse) for nodejs client.

What could be the wrong?

Comment: Host networking doesn't work on Docker Desktop or other VM-based solutions.  Are you running the Docker engine directly on a native-Linux host, or do you have some other setup?  In almost all cases I'd recommend `docker run -p` publishing individual ports over using the `--network host` option to disable Docker's networking layer.

Comment: Got it @DavidMaze, using port mapping worked.

Comment: You can write the same in answer so that I can accept it, it can help fellow readers to get the answer quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host networking only "works" in one specific host-OS configuration (running Docker engine without Docker Desktop on a native-Linux system).  It generally disables Docker's networking layer and with it some key features, like connecting to other containers by name and the ability to hide or remap ports on the hosts.  For most cases I'd recommend avoiding host networking.

The standard way to get access to a container's port is by publishing a port using a `docker run -p` option.  In your example the container seems to listen on ports 8123 and 9000, so you'd need two `-p` options

```bash
docker run -p 8123:8123 -p 9000:9000 ...
# without `--network=host`
```

In those options the second port numbers are the port inside the container, and must match what the server process inside the container is using.  The first port number is the host port and can be any port that's not already in use.  In your browser or in client code running directly on the host, you'd use the first port number.

Docker documentation mentions "exposing" ports as well; this is an obsolete option from first-generation Docker networking and does nothing in modern Docker.  Port mapping and host networking aren't compatible and you should get a warning if you have both `--net host` and a `-p` option; make sure you remove the `--network=host` setting.